Is it an Invention or Discovery
Since years ago, I was asking myself if someone made a good software program should we say that:

He invented a software program

or

He discovered a software program

It's strongly related to the industry type you can think of it like music:
Beethoven composed a beautiful tune
tune and our program and many in other industries, are they inventions or discoveries.
The difference between both terms are known, the problem revolves around the classification. those industries strongly depend on innovation and creativity, so, which term should you use for a product, is it an invention?
For example, is Facebook app an invention or just a discovery ?
most of use will bias to invention term, but that facebook app was built depending on some programming languages (like music tunes in music).
see, programming languages were already exist, but someone made some mix and produce an app like facebook or even a music song.
So, is it an invention or a discovery, i think it's a logical problem not a language related.
Thank you.

It is language related and you have not looked up the words. Maybe that would be a good idea.

An invention is something you create.
For example, Alexander Graham Bell is credited with inventing the telephone. He conceived the idea, designed it, built it, and patented it.
A discovery is something you find.
For example, you might discover a new species of animal. The animal already existed, all you did was find it.
There are other words, such as create, compose, design etc that better suit specific contexts. We'd normally say someone created a computer program (or 'programmed', although it seems weird to repeat the word - perhaps he programmed an application). Compose is synonymous with music, but for songs with lyrics we normally say someone wrote them.

the difference between both terms are known, the problem revolves around the classification. those industries strongly depend on innovation and creativity, so, which term should you use for a product, is it an invention.

@A-E "Invention" is strongly associated with the creation of something entirely new, especially technical innovations like the car, the telephone, the computer etc. "Create" is the broader term and includes new kinds of things - for example, someone might 'create' a new kind of a product that already exists. We wouldn't say someone 'invented' a television programme because that's just a new kind of something that already exists.

got it, thanks.
